# Can you get missed weapon mods in New Game+?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When you begin New Game+ with your character, you import many things - weapons, armor, experience, and weapon mods.

I wonder - when you plan NG+, during missions can you obtain same equipment as in normal game? For example, in normal game you obtain Shotgun Shredder Mod 3 (out of maximum level 5), and is it possible that during NG+ you obtain on missions other 2 levels? Or are these mods just cut out of mission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any of your mods are sub level 5, you will be able to find weapon mods of that type wherever they would usually spawn, regardless of whether you have collected the mod in that particular location or not. When a weapon mod reaches level 5, it stops appearing in levels altogether.

To reiterate, if weapon mod X spawns in levels A, B and C, and you have collected it in A and C on your first playthrough, you can find it in all possible locations (A, B or C) until the mod upgrades to level 5.

Note that on the first playthough, 2 units of each mod are available for purchase from shops. If you bought them on your first playthrough, you will not be able to buy 2 more on subsequent playthroughs.